# Realm database size goes x100 when using an async thread

Tags: json, swift, multithreading, realm, alamofire

So I have some code that parses background data into my Realm database. When I do the call without an async thread, the database takes around 10 seconds to fill (JSON with 1000 entries) and the app freezes during that time because swiftyJson is slow (native JSON also takes about 2 secs).

When I add the async call, it fixes the freeze issue, BUT my database is now 50 MB instead of 500kb before.... Any idea what is going on? All help is welcome

```
    func loadDataForLocalCategory() {
        let URL = "SomeURL"
        Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    for item in json["result"].arrayValue {
                        let localCategory = LocalDataCategory()
                        localCategory.id = item["id"].intValue
                        // print(item["name"].stringValue)
                        localCategory.name = item["name"].stringValue
                        try! realm.write {
                            realm.add(localCategory,update: true)
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually best practice in Realm to try and batch as many changes as you can to as fewer write transactions (i.e. the `realm.write { }` closure) as possible.

At the moment, you're opening a new write transaction for each iteration of the for loop (i.e., 1000 write transactions), which might be causing the file size to balloon out due to the way Realm snapshots data on different threads.

I'd recommend moving that realm write closure to outside of that for loop:

```
if let value = response.result.value {
   let realm = try! Realm()
   let json = JSON(value)

   realm.write {
      for item in json["result"].arrayValue {
         let localCategory = LocalDataCategory()
         localCategory.id = item["id"].intValue
         // print(item["name"].stringValue)
         localCategory.name = item["name"].stringValue
         realm.add(localCategory,update: true)
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if that helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, it did help :D so weird that it worked fine on the main thread, and explodes on the async_thread.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! Haha yeah, it's exactly because it's on a different thread. Realm maintains different copies of the same data so writing on one thread won't kill reads occurring on another. But obviously depending on the amount of transactions occurring on separate threads, that can affect the physical size on disk.